# Customizing JMeter Listener

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to customize JMeter Listener "Summary Report".

It gives Average, Minimum and Maximum Elapsed Time. I need to subtract some constant value from each request Elapsed Time. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and best way to do this is to edit the raw results file. Personally I like to use awk for this sort of thing but I guess you could also use a spreadsheet.

Once you've amended the file you can then reload it into the listener. This isn't super intuitive but where you see `Write results to file / Read from file` you can enter the path to the amended file and this will then update the Summary (or any other listener) Report.

Remember to use CTRL-E to clear the existing data from memory before loading the new file otherwise it will merge both sets.

You *could* also customise the listener plugin by changing its source but that would be a bad idea for such a use case.